# How to avoid getting "constant expression" on if's?

Tags: c, if-statement, assert, assertions, constant-expression

I have an `assert` macro that resolves to an `if`, something like this:

```
#define assert(expr) \
if (!(expr)) \
{ \
    handle_failed_assert(); \
}
```

Ignore how `handle_failed_assert()` works, and you don't need to cite the `do { ... } while(0)` trick. Please, focus on the functionality behind this.

Now, the real question comes. Sometimes I want to force and assert, and make it meaningful. So we use this:

```
assert(!"Assert cause carefully described.");
```

The problem is that we have this compiler, *vrxcc*, based on *RVCT 2.2*, that throws this warning when compiling that:

```
#236-D: controlling expression is constant
```

Of course, that resolves to a compile constant `if`.

How could I trick the compiler into accepting that?

Comment: I don't know if this would help the warning, but I would use the `?:` operator rather than an `if` statement so you don't have to worry about the expansion of the macro being a compound statement. It can simply be an expression. You might could use `&&` or `||` in place of `?:` too, and these might silence the warning.

Comment: I like that. Something like `if (expr && handle_failed_assert())` might work. I'll try and report that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem ultimately boils down to "my compiler is too smart, how do I make it stop complaining about something that, yes, is true and is often a programmer mistake, but in this case is *not* a programmer mistake".  There are only two ways to do that:

- Outwit the compiler.  This is compiler-dependent.
- Tell the compiler "don't complain, this is not a mistake."  This is compiler-dependent.

I know nothing about vrxcc.  R's comment goes towards doing the first.  This sort of thing is almost guaranteed to work:

```
extern int __truefunc(void);
#define assert(expr) ((__truefunc() && (expr)) || __assert_fail(#expr))
```

where `truefunc` is a function that always returns 1, and that you can compile separately to outwit the compiler.  The cost, of course, is that darned useless run-time call.

The "tell the compiler" method is nicer, but requires some sort of compiler documentation assist.

---

Addendum: it occurred to me in the shower that in your particular case, you've already decided to panic, so you could just have a `panic` function, and call that here.  The disadvantage is that you have to change all your existing `common_assert(!"some string")` calls, but at least you can do that mechanically.

It might be nice if the language had a two-argument `assert` built in or as a standard thing.  The FreeBSD kernel uses `KASSERT` for this these days, more or less as:

```
#define KASSERT(expr, panic_args) \
    do { if (!(expr)) panic panic_args; } while (0)
```

which is a bit klunky syntactically, but is nicely flexible:

```
KASSERT(foo.field == FOO_MAGIC,
    ("memory overwrite of foo data structure: %d != %d",
        foo.field, FOO_MAGIC));
```

Comment: So, is it actually necessary to make `__truefunc()` an extern function? I was about to suggest something similar using a volatile integer.

Comment: @Spidey Also, I must strongly suggest that you name your macro something other than `assert()`, if for no other reason than to avoid severely confusing anyone reading your code. The macro named `assert()` is, if you `#include <assert.h>`, defined by the C standard to call `abort()` if the condition is false. If you're writing an assert-type macro (or function) that actually handles the error, `assert()` is a bad choice of name.

Comment: It's actually `common_assert`, don't worry about that.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: not necessarily; an extern volatile is likely to work too.